# filepond in Vue : i add edit and resize plugin BUT edit icon doesnt show

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, filepond

i have added file pond to Nuxt project and have installed filepond edit and  resize plugin . but it doesnt show edit icon !

this in file-pond plugin i have made to globally use it

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import vueFilePond from "vue-filepond";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import FilePondPluginImageValidateSize from 'filepond-plugin-image-validate-size'
import FilePondPluginImageCrop from 'filepond-plugin-image-crop'
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation';
import FilePondPluginImageEdit from 'filepond-plugin-image-edit';

const FilePond = vueFilePond(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview, FilePondPluginImageValidateSize ,FilePondPluginImageCrop ,FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,FilePondPluginImageEdit
 )
Vue.component('file-pond', FilePond)
```

and this is component code

```html
  <file-pond
            name="test"
            ref="pond"
            label-idle="Drop files here..."
            v-bind:allow-multiple="true"
            accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
            imagePreviewHeight="170"
            imageCropAspectRatio="1:1"
            imageResizeTargetWidth="200"
            imageResizeTargetHeight="200"
            v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
          />
```

as you see in below pic there is not "edit" button
[image]

i mean this button that in filepond document examples displayed when image is get selected
[image]

Comment: Can you not install any additional plugin, try the bare minimum and see if it's available? If it's not, do you have an error? Or maybe something in the DOM?

Comment: Also, check your vue devtools to find out if the component is present or not.

Comment: i tested it without plugin and edit icon is not present and in vue dev tools file pond component exists and there is no error in console

Comment: Then, it's maybe a CSS issue? Is it maybe hidden? Or with a width of 0px? Maybe try to import it in a simpler page or to inspect it with your browser devtools.

Comment: i checked html tags and css but it doesnt exists

Comment: If the vue component exists, it should exist in the DOM too.

Comment: just file-pond component exists , plugins component doesnt

Comment: Where is your first snippet actually written? Can you give us more context? Also, where did you find out how to import the plugins? Can you share the resource?

Comment: Did you try to use their codesandbox as a starting point?

Comment: i found out import plugins in their document , the only different is that i use type script

Comment: in their codesand box also there is no edit icon ,

Comment: this is their sandbox i forked and added some plugins https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filepond-live-demo-forked-blfct?file=/src/components/FilePondDemo.vue
and it doesnt work again

Comment: I'm not sure what `filepond-plugin-image-edit` is for but the install methods described here are not the ones that you did use above: https://pqina.nl/pintura/docs/v8/getting-started/installation/ Maybe try some alternative install from there.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3v8zoprp7
this is official vue-filepond example and even here there s no edit icon

Comment: now i undestand that another option dont work also , for example "accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png" props that i passed to file pond component is also doesn't work and it get all formats

Comment: Hi, the image-edit plugin is a proxy to the deprecated Doka Image Editor component, it doesn't have editing capabilities itself. If the component is not loaded the edit button doesn't show. It has since been replaced with https://pqina.nl/pintura

Comment: @mortezamortezaie Did you find the answer?